Getting real time volume data from binance api
I'm using binance's mini_ticker to get real time info of all assets being trade in BINANCE, in order to store this information.
I'm coding in python and using binance-connector. The relevant part of my code is:
from binance.websocket.spot.websocket_stream import SpotWebsocketStreamClient as Client
import json
def Message_handler(_,message):
    message=json.loads(message)
    do_something_with(message)
client = Client(on_message=Message_handler)
client.mini_ticker(symbols=["bnbusdt",'ethusdt']) # retrieves every pair

After parsing, message['BTCUSDT']['c'] returns the close price of the mentioned pair every second. However, message['BTCUSDT']['v'] returns the total amount of BTC having been traded (for USDT) in the las 24 hours, which means that, at the next second, it will return the previous amount, plus the amount traded at the very last second, minus the amount traded at the first second of the previous 24h rolling window.
This means I cannot get the amount of BTC traded in the very last second from the mini_ticker (or ticker) stream. To be clear, if I substract v_(t-1) from v_t, I won't get the amount of BTC traded in the last second, but: "the amount traded in the last second minus the amount traded in the first second of the t_1 24h rolling window". As I can't know the v from that single first second of the t_1 24h rolling window, I can't find the amount of BTC traded in the last second of the new window.
I could get this information from the 1s kline_stream of each pair I'm interested in but, as I'm retrieving information for about 300 plus pairs, this approach will go beyond the API's limit and I would be blocked.
Could you recommend me an approach to get the information I need?
